# Regular Expression: Filter out phrases with space

Tags: regex

How do I use Regex to filter out phrases containing space? For example in a txt:

```
Singapore
United States of America
Zimbabwe
```

How to I use regex to get the result:

```
Singapore
Zimbabwe
```

?

Comment: You can't achieve this with regex, because the separator for countries (space) is the same as the separator for words composing a country.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, they are actually in separate lines, I dont know why new lines get deleted when I post this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing a regex replacement on the following pattern:

```
^.*[ ].*
```

Then just replace that with empty string, to remove the entire line.  This pattern would match any line containing one or more spaces.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

The regex below will give you the lines that don't have space in it. You can match the words one by one and store them to get the result you want depending on the language you use.

```
^(\w+[^ ])$
```

What it does is. It scans from the beginning of the line to the end of the line. It looks for a word and if there is a space in the line it doesn't match it. So, we get the output below.

**Output**

```
Singapore
Zimbabwe
```

Here is the [result](https://regex101.com/r/cssPeB/1).